# xamarin facebook authentication no longer supported for android

Tags: facebook, authentication, xamarin, browser

following the microsoft examples as documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-cosmosdb-auth
Everything is fine up to the point where I run the xamarin forms app to log in using facebook to get a token.

The error from the emulator when I try to login is this:
For your account security, logging in to Facebook from an embedded browser is disabled. To continue, download and log in to Facebook app on your device and try again.

I have tried downloading the app on the emulator, but that makes no difference, my facebook app is in development state but even then it should at least get me to the login page and allow using a test user.
It seems that facebook stopped supporting android login using embedded browsers from 5 October 2021. See here:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/06/28/deprecating-support-fb-login-authentication-android-embedded-browsers/

Would it be possible to please update the sample with either b2c or with an alternate method or details of how to get facebook auth working again?
If anyone have examples that someone new to these concepts could follow that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FB did not stop supporting Android, they stopped supporting login via **embedded** browsers.  This is a change that was publicly announced long before it was implemented.  If you want MS to update their docs, there is a **Feedback** link at the bottom of every page.  SO does not write the MS docs.

Comment: Thanks Jason, would you happen to have a handy link to a sample or information on  how to hook facebook authentication into xamarin forms app for use with a resource token broker, without using embedded browsers? Any actual help appreciated :-).

Comment: Could you try this on a real device to see if the problem persists ?

Comment: thanks ColeX. Same issue on my phone as well. Following this link: https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/03/09/using-native-facebook-login-button-in-xamarin-forms/ Able to adapt the xamarin forms app to get a FB token. Changed resource token broker, pulling email address from the token as the user id. The token broker works only from postman when run locally, azure web service rejects my authentication when done this way. So Progress but not there yet, wish the example could be adapted. Getting closer.